# How to transparent the main window in WinUI-3

Tags: c#, winui-3

Do not judge strictly. I just started learning WinUI. Using WPF I could make the main window transparent right in the XAML markup. Is it possible to make the main window transparent using Reunion? I need this to make the program window of my shape.The window object has so few properties. I only found how to change the TitleBar.
And more:

- Can I use reunion to make rounded corners on windows 10 as on windows 11?
- Does Mica material work on windows 10?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Transparent windows are not yet supported but it's tracked as a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2956).

> Can I use reunion to make rounded corners on windows 10 as on windows 11?

No, at least not using the AppWindow layer that is used to produce the rounded corners in Windows 11.

> Does Mica material work on windows 10?

No, Mica is exclusive to Windows 11. At least for now.