# How to apply Mica as a Window background

Tags: c#, window, winui-3

I'm trying to make my WinUI 3 `Window` have a Mica background. I am importing the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media` package, then using the following code to set the window's background to Mica:

```csharp
MicaController micaController = new MicaController();
Window.Current.SetSystemBackdrop(micaController.CreateBackdrop());
```

Ideally, this would also work for any other `Window` backdrop, (Acrylic and Mica Alt), not just Mica.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69241459/how-to-transparent-the-main-window-in-winui-3), but it was no help.

I'm using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76536129/2411960) in another question:

First, create this helper class:

**WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper.cs.**

```cs
internal class WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper
{
    private object? _dispatcherQueueController = null;

    public void EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController()
    {
        if (Windows.System.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread() != null)
        {
            // one already exists, so we'll just use it.
            return;
        }

        if (_dispatcherQueueController == null)
        {
            DispatcherQueueOptions options;
            options.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DispatcherQueueOptions));
            options.threadType = 2;    // DQTYPE_THREAD_CURRENT
            options.apartmentType = 2; // DQTAT_COM_STA

            CreateDispatcherQueueController(options, ref _dispatcherQueueController);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("CoreMessaging.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateDispatcherQueueController([In] DispatcherQueueOptions options, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object? dispatcherQueueController);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct DispatcherQueueOptions
    {
        internal int dwSize;
        internal int threadType;
        internal int apartmentType;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops;
using WinRT; // required to support Window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>()

namespace AcrylicBrushExample;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper? _wsdqHelper;

    // See separate sample below for implementation
    private DesktopAcrylicController? _acrylicController;

    private MicaController? _micaController;

    private SystemBackdropConfiguration? _configurationSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var result = TrySetMicaBackdrop();
    }

    private bool TrySetMicaBackdrop()
    {
        if (MicaController.IsSupported() is true)
        {
            _wsdqHelper = new WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper();
            _wsdqHelper.EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController();

            // Hooking up the policy object
            _configurationSource = new SystemBackdropConfiguration();
            this.Activated += Window_Activated;
            this.Closed += Window_Closed;
            ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualThemeChanged += Window_ThemeChanged;

            // Initial configuration state.
            _configurationSource.IsInputActive = true;
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();

            _micaController = new MicaController();

            // Enable the system backdrop.
            // Note: Be sure to have "using WinRT;" to support the Window.As<...>() call.
            _micaController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(this.As<Microsoft.UI.Composition.ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());
            _micaController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(_configurationSource);
            return true; // succeeded
        }

        return false; // Mica is not supported on this system
    }

    private void Window_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            _configurationSource.IsInputActive = args.WindowActivationState != WindowActivationState.Deactivated;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
    {
        // Make sure any Mica/Acrylic controller is disposed so it doesn't try to
        // use this closed window.
        if (_acrylicController is not null)
        {
            _acrylicController.Dispose();
            _acrylicController = null;
        }

        this.Activated -= Window_Activated;
        _configurationSource = null;
    }

    private void Window_ThemeChanged(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();
        }
    }

    private void SetConfigurationSourceTheme()
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            switch (((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualTheme)
            {
                case ElementTheme.Dark:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Dark;
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Light:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Light;
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Default:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Default;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising but I receive the error: `The type or namespace name 'WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I also get this same error for `EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController`.

Comment: The helper class is missing. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great! Works nicely now! Can this work with other backgrounds, such as Acrylic and Mica Alt, and if so, how?

Comment: You can see Acrylic in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76536129/2411960) or in the [WinUI 3 Galley App](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/winui-3-gallery/9P3JFPWWDZRC?hl=en-us&gl=us).

Comment: Yes, just found that out. How would I make my custom titlebar follow Mica or Acrylic?

Comment: Should be possible. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/mica#:~:text=To%20give%20your%20app%27s%20window%20a%20seamless%20look%2C%20Mica%20should%20be%20visible%20in%20the%20title%20bar%20if%20you%20choose%20to%20apply%20the%20material%20to%20your%20app.%20You%20can%20show%20Mica%20in%20the%20title%20bar%20by%20extending%20your%20app%20into%20the%20non%2Dclient%20area%20and%20creating%20a%20transparent%20custom%20title%20bar.%20For%20more%20info%2C%20see%20Title%20bar.).