# Easiest way to set the window background to an acrylic brush in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

To be clear I do not want to use **WinEx** or **Win2D** NuGets.
I want the window to look like fogged glass, where the desktop can be slightly seen through the window.
I know the way to do it in **WinUI2** was something like this...

```
Window currentWindow = Window.Current;
AcrylicBrush acrylicBrush = new AcrylicBrush();
acrylicBrush.BackgroundSource = AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop;
acrylicBrush.TintColor = Colors.Transparent;
acrylicBrush.FallbackColor = Colors.Transparent;
acrylicBrush.TintOpacity = 0.2;
currentWindow.Background = acrylicBrush;
ElementCompositionPreview.SetIsHostBackdrop(currentWindow, true);
```

But `ElementCompositionPreview.SetIsHostBackdrop` and `AcrylicBackgroundSource.HostBackdrop` do not exist anymore in **WinUI3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the sample code in the **WinUI 3 Gallery App**. I just made the fields nullable and changed a few member names.

First, create a helper class:

**WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper.cs**

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AcrylicBrushExample;

internal class WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper
{
    private object? _dispatcherQueueController = null;

    public void EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController()
    {
        if (Windows.System.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread() != null)
        {
            // one already exists, so we'll just use it.
            return;
        }

        if (_dispatcherQueueController == null)
        {
            DispatcherQueueOptions options;
            options.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DispatcherQueueOptions));
            options.threadType = 2;    // DQTYPE_THREAD_CURRENT
            options.apartmentType = 2; // DQTAT_COM_STA

            CreateDispatcherQueueController(options, ref _dispatcherQueueController);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("CoreMessaging.dll")]
    private static extern int CreateDispatcherQueueController([In] DispatcherQueueOptions options, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object? dispatcherQueueController);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct DispatcherQueueOptions
    {
        internal int dwSize;
        internal int threadType;
        internal int apartmentType;
    }
}
```

then in your MainWindow:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Composition.SystemBackdrops;
using WinRT; // required to support Window.As<ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>()

namespace AcrylicBrushExample;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper? _wsdqHelper;

    // See separate sample below for implementation
    private DesktopAcrylicController? _acrylicController;

    private SystemBackdropConfiguration? _configurationSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var result = TrySetAcrylicBackdrop();
    }

    private bool TrySetAcrylicBackdrop()
    {
        if (DesktopAcrylicController.IsSupported() is true)
        {
            _wsdqHelper = new WindowsSystemDispatcherQueueHelper();
            _wsdqHelper.EnsureWindowsSystemDispatcherQueueController();

            // Hooking up the policy object
            _configurationSource = new SystemBackdropConfiguration();
            this.Activated += Window_Activated;
            this.Closed += Window_Closed;
            ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualThemeChanged += Window_ThemeChanged;

            // Initial configuration state.
            _configurationSource.IsInputActive = true;
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();

            _acrylicController = new DesktopAcrylicController();

            // Enable the system backdrop.
            // Note: Be sure to have "using WinRT;" to support the Window.As<...>() call.
            _acrylicController.AddSystemBackdropTarget(this.As<Microsoft.UI.Composition.ICompositionSupportsSystemBackdrop>());
            _acrylicController.SetSystemBackdropConfiguration(_configurationSource);
            return true; // succeeded
        }

        return false; // Acrylic is not supported on this system
    }

    private void Window_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            _configurationSource.IsInputActive = args.WindowActivationState != WindowActivationState.Deactivated;
        }
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, WindowEventArgs args)
    {
        // Make sure any Mica/Acrylic controller is disposed so it doesn't try to
        // use this closed window.
        if (_acrylicController is not null)
        {
            _acrylicController.Dispose();
            _acrylicController = null;
        }

        this.Activated -= Window_Activated;
        _configurationSource = null;
    }

    private void Window_ThemeChanged(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            SetConfigurationSourceTheme();
        }
    }

    private void SetConfigurationSourceTheme()
    {
        if (_configurationSource is not null)
        {
            switch (((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualTheme)
            {
                case ElementTheme.Dark:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Dark;
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Light:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Light;
                    break;
                case ElementTheme.Default:
                    _configurationSource.Theme = SystemBackdropTheme.Default;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked. I had looked through the gallery example but didn't realize the WinRT part.

My "poor man's" version...
static AcrylicBrush _acrylicBrush = new AcrylicBrush();
void MainWindowOnActivated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{
        _acrylicBrush.TintTransitionDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
 _acrylicBrush.TintOpacity = 0.15;
 _acrylicBrush.TintLuminosityOpacity = 0.1;
 _acrylicBrush.TintColor = Microsoft.UI.Colors.SpringGreen;
 _acrylicBrush.FallbackColor = Microsoft.UI.Colors.Transparent;
 this.Root.Background = _acrylicBrush;
}